Error response from daemon: No such image in Gitlab CI/CD Pipeline
I'm trying to execute a pipeline using GitLab CI/CD, and it fails at delivery stage, it gets me the next error:
Login Succeeded
$ docker tag backend-node-prueba:latest myuser/backend-node-prueba:latest
Error response from daemon: No such image: backend-node-prueba:latest

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, this is how I made my .gitlab-ci.yml:
image: docker:latest

services:
  - docker:dind

stages:
 - build      # implementará las construcciones del back y el front
 - test       # implementará todas las pruebas
 - delivery   # implementará creación de release, creación de tags de docker y push a docker hub


build-backend:
  stage: build
  before_script:
    - docker ps -q | xargs -r docker stop
    - docker ps -a -q | xargs -r docker rm
    - docker system prune -a -f
  script:
    - cd Backend
    - docker build -t backend-node-prueba:latest .


build-frontend:
  stage: build
  script:
    - cd Frontend
    - docker build -t frontend-react-prueba:latest .

run-tests:
  image: node:18
  stage: test
  script:
    - cd Backend
    - npm install
    - npm test

publish-backend-image:
  stage: delivery
  before_script:
    - docker login --username myuser --password $DOCKER_TOKEN
  script:
    - docker tag backend-node-prueba:latest myuser/backend-node-prueba:latest
    - docker push myuser/backend-node-prueba:latest

publish-frontend-image:
  stage: delivery
  before_script:
    - docker login --username myuser --password $DOCKER_TOKEN
  script:
    - docker tag frontend-react-prueba:latest myuser/frontend-react-prueba:latest
    - docker push myuser/frontend-react-prueba:latest


please help :( I've spent hours in this. Thank you!

You have to tag and build in the same stage, otherwise it is different machine

Jobs may run on different machines. Here as you're using images runners, it will always run in different containers
